# express + express-graphql app crashes, unexpected token pretty = optionsData.pretty ?? false;

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I'm trying to get an express-graphql app up and running and I've been following the example code from the official documentation. However it keeps crashing and I'm getting this error in my terminal after running npm start.

```
node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:47
    pretty = optionsData.pretty ?? false;
                                 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1067:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1115:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

Tried to re-install the packages and start over, but I keep getting the same error, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the current version of `express-graphql`. Please use the previous version until a patched version is released.

```
npm install express-graphql@0.9.0
```

Edit: This has been fixed in version `0.10.1`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using version 0.10.0 downgrade it to 0.9.0

```
npm i express-graphql@0.9.0
```